# DVD-RW does not mount in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: mount, dvd, cd, media

I try to use CDs and DVDs in my Ubuntu Precise Pangolin (12.04 LTS), but the system doesn't mount the DVD-Recorder when the DVD or CD is ready to use. What is the solution for this problem? How Ubuntu 12.04 LTS can mount optical media (CD, DVD, Blu-Ray) recorders?

Comment: what is the output of `dmesg | grep sr0` ? and also when you mount the ususal way, what error are you getting?

Comment: I also have same problem - it seems to work ONCE - that is ubuntu 12.04 will correctly auto mount a blank DVD ONCE per session then any subsequent blank DVD put into tray will NOT auto mount until next reboot - this has been true for several ubuntu releases

Answer (score 1):

**non-blank media**:
As it seems, by default non-blank media (CD, DVD) does not mount automatically. But it should show up in nautilus. Click on the entry in your left side of a nautilus browser under **devices** and the media should mount.

**blank media**:
Blank media is mounting automatically on my Ubuntu 12.04. I think it is the default behaviour.

**nothing shows up**:
If there is nothing new in the **devices** area in nautilus, this is a bad sign. Your drive might not be connected (check the cables).

As *ashutosh* pointed out, to find out if the recorder was recognized, type `dmesg | grep "sr0"` in a terminal. You should get a response similar to:

```
[    1.649270] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.649445] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

**check mounted non-blank media**:
To be sure there it is not mounted execute this in a terminal: `mount | grep "/dev/sr"`
If the response is blank there is no non-blank media mounted in your media drive. Blank media is not showing up here.

**Note**:
your drive might be called `sr1` or `sr2` if you have several; in that case replace `sr0` with `sr1` in that case (or simply `sr` to catch them all).